# How to wait until services are ready

Tags: linux, shell, docker, jenkins, sh

I have been setting up a Jenkins pipeline using docker images. Now I need to run various services like MySQL, Redis, Memcache, Beanstalkd and Elasticsearch. To wait the job until MySQL is ready, I am using the following command :

```
sh "while ! mysqladmin ping -u root -h mysqlhost ; do sleep 1; done"
sh 'echo MySQL server is up and running'
```

Where `mysqlhost` is the hostname I have provided for the container. Similarly, I need to check and wait for `Redis, Memcached, Beanstalkd and Elasticsearch`. But pinging to these services are not working as it is done for `MySQL` . How can I implement this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) mention this script to manage container readiness checks: https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it

I also use this one which is compatible with Alpine:
https://github.com/eficode/wait-for

Answer (score 0):

You can do a curl to this services in order to check if they are alive or not.
For redis you can also do https://redis.io/commands/ping

Comment: You can do it in a loop until you get the reply needed. 
For kubernetes pods, we do something similar. We make a loop curl to an endpoint and until we dont get the 200 and we dont continue.